# Mule Dataweave: using when and Map

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a requirement to retrieve AmountRequired depending on the category from the below input and list out all the repeated elements.

```
<root>
    <Unspecified>
        <Category>T03</Category>
        <AmountRequired>993</AmountRequired>
        <ExcessAmount>250</ExcessAmount>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
    </Unspecified>
    <Unspecified>
        <Category>T03</Category>
        <AmountRequired>9903</AmountRequired>
        <ExcessAmount>250</ExcessAmount>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
    </Unspecified>
    <Unspecified>
        <Category>P02</Category>
        <AmountRequired>992</AmountRequired>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
    </Unspecified>
    <Unspecified>
        <Category>A29</Category>
        <AmountRequired>929</AmountRequired>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
    </Unspecified>
</root>
```

I want to get the out put as below. When there are 2 tags of T03 its should display both the amounts as below. Also if a Category doesn't exist it doesn't for example P05 and if we have the transformation for it then it errors out that P05 doesn't exist, so is there a way to get over the error even if the input xml doesn't contain the P05 Category?

```
<amountRequired>
        <amount>929</amount>
        <currency>GBP</currency>
        <exchangeRate>1</exchangeRate>
        <amountInSystemCurrency>550</amountInSystemCurrency>
    </amountRequired>
<amountRequired>
    <amount>993</amount>
    <currency></currency>
    <exchangeRate></exchangeRate>
    <amountInSystemCurrency></amountInSystemCurrency>
</amountRequired>
<amountRequired>
    <amount>9903</amount>
    <currency></currency>
    <exchangeRate></exchangeRate>
    <amountInSystemCurrency></amountInSystemCurrency>
</amountRequired>
<amountRequired>
        <amount>992</amount>
        <currency></currency>
        <exchangeRate></exchangeRate>
        <amountInSystemCurrency></amountInSystemCurrency>
    </amountRequired>
```

Highly appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
using (T03=payload.root.*Unspecified filter ($.Category == 'T03')){
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598550/mule-dataweave-using-when-and-map
    amountRequired:{  
    amount:T03.AmountRequired[0] default 0,
    currency:"",
    exchangeRate:"",
    amountInSystemCurrency:""
} 
}
```

It uses a variable T03 to hold the T03 category item filtered from original payload.
`amount: T03.AmountRequired[0] default 0` will output amount from T03 when exist otherwise default 0.

**In comments to this answer, you seem to have changed the requirement :). Anyways, editing this answer for to accommodate below comment "

*I have edited the question, hope it makes sense. I want to output all tags (note:T03 is repeated and want to output both of them) – Neil24 13 mins ago*"**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    root : { (payload.root.*Unspecified map 
        amountRequired: {
            amount:$.AmountRequired unless $.Category != 'T03' otherwise 0,
            currency:"",
            exchangeRate:"",
            amountInSystemCurrency:""
        }
    )}
}
```

This is very straight forward transformation and amount field is 0 unless the current category is T03.
In original question you had mentioned that you need amount only if its a T03 category so there is unless .. otherwise check, if you want amount for every category, just remove it.

**Hope That Helps!**

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Thanks, I am new to using stackoverflow, I am not sure where I need to accep the answer.

Comment: Do you see tickmark on left side of my answer, click it to accept. Check - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Hi, I have a further requirement where there are 2 unspecified items with the same Category 'T03' (I have edited the input xml to have 2 elements with T03) and it should list both of them.  I have tried adding payload.root.*Unspecified map before using but didn't work. Highly appreciate your help.Thanks.

Comment: you mean there should be two amount elements? What is the sample output for two?

Comment: I have added the sample output for T03 by editing the question itself. So it should have 2 amountRequired tags for T03, one with 993 amount and another with 9903 amount in it. Thanks

Comment: Also, another thing is the application throws error if there is no category for example P02 and there is a transformation for P02, saying that P02 doesn't exist. So is there is a way of getting away with the error if a category doesn't exist and there is a tranformation for it? Thanks for your help

Comment: ok, can you please open different question for P02? That helps to keep forum clean.

Comment: Are you trying to output all tags except A29? Sorry I am confused now, what is the requirement? I see you want all T03 categories and your sample output also contains P02. What is the exact requirement?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it makes sense. I want to output all tags (note:T03 is repeated and want to output both of them)

Comment: It gets only the T03 amounts but not the other's  (others are coming as 0). In the input xml example, only T03 is repeated but there might be instances where the other Categories might also be repated and the transformation should handle that as well. Thanks

Comment: I think you missed to read "In original question you had mentioned that you need amount only if its a T03 category so there is unless .. otherwise check, if you want amount for every category, just remove it." below that code. Remove that unless ... otherwise. Also, it will output every category that will in your input, irrespective of how many times it occurs in input.

Comment: ok, thats cool, but what if I want to only output all the T03 ant not others. As the others are coming as zero, which, I want them to be removed completely. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Comment: if you just want to map all T03's then you need to filter out payload first, instead of using `payload.root.*Unspecified map {`, use it like `(payload.root.*Unspecified filter $.Category == 'T03') map { .... rest is same`. This will first filter collection for T03 and then pass it to map. Try it.